# Authorization header not present in Graphql Request

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, apollo, next.js

I have a:

1. Frontend: React, Next.js. Uses apollo client.
2. Backend: NodeJs, Express server with a GraphQL endpoint.

I apply a cookie to the GraphQL apollo client, here is the code of the instantiation.

```
  ({ ctx, headers, initialState }) =>
    new ApolloClient({
      uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
      cache: cache,
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
      authorization: Cookies.get('token') ? `Bearer ${Cookies.get('token')}` : ""},
      typeDefs,
      resolvers
      }));
```

When I use useQuery in my React component, I send a graphQL request to the backend. I have middleware set up to authenticate the request by checking for the token. The code:

```
export let checkToken = (req : any, res : any, next : any) => {
  let token = req.headers['authorization']; // I also tried req.headers.authorization
  if (token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    token = token.slice(7, token.length);
  }

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, config.cookieKey, (err : any, decoded : any) => {
      if (err) {
        Logger.info("Token in request is not valid.");
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Token is not valid'
        });
      } else {
        Logger.info("Token in request is valid.");
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    Logger.info("No token in request found.");
    return res.json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Auth token is not supplied'
    });
  }
};
```

The issue is that the req.headers.authorization is undefined once it reaches the backend. I have console logged the cookie token before on the client side and it does return a cookie.

**CORS EDIT**

```
 app.use(function(_req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", `${config.frontend_url}`);
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
      next();
    });
```

**Console.log(req.headers) edit**

```
{ accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  authorization: '',
  'content-length': '185',
  'user-agent': 'node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
  connection: 'close',
  host: 'localhost:4000' }

{ accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  authorization: '',
  'content-length': '185',
  'user-agent': 'node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
  connection: 'close',
  host: 'localhost:4000' }
```

Comment: did you enabled CORS? and did you expose Authorization headers ?

Comment: Yup. I've added the CORs stuff in an edit to the OP.

Comment: And if console.log(req.headers) do you get other headers?

Comment: After checking this console.log:

The client sends this request several times. All the headers are there, but out of the 4 times the client sent this request, the authorization header was only present once. And the value was ""

Comment: Actually, correction: The first request had no authorization header, the next two did (it was empty) and the last didn't

Comment: how do you get your cookie? if you hardcode a random string you get the header?

Comment: When it's hardcoded it is present in the console.log(req.headers)! 

Would it be the case that Cookies.get('token) doesn't happen in time before the apollo client sends the query request?

Comment: Probably cookies.get() works client side but not serverside, wich module are you using to get cookies?

Comment: Js-cookie to get the cookies.

The way it works is that the client sends a google authorization code to the backend, backend validates its, and then using jwt signs the json token package. this is then sent to the client as this encoded string, which is placed in a cookie. then i use this cookie and send it to the backend as an authorization header where it's verified by the jwt library. 

it started consistently sending the header now after i placed some code into a try and catch... i'm not sure what i changed. but thank you for your help.